# Tools for generating database records

Tags: mysql, database, data-generation

I will be happy to know if there is any available tool which can generate data records based to a specific schema rules.

At this moment I work with CakePHP and I'm new to mysql workbench, but i have no problem if there is a tool which can generate some data and export it to xml or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of mine colleagues just find http://www.generatedata.com/#generator but please replay me, if there are better/popular products.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Codeignitor and Django

Comment: those are web frameworks, php and respectively Phyton frameworks, and they have nothing to do with databases:(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/blacktea/populate-db-now

Works like a charm for our development team :-)